# match the first two elements of a list

Tags: f#

I have a list :

> [objA;objB;objC;objD]

I need to do the following reduction :

> obj -> obj -> obj

ie :

> objA objB -> objB'

and then take back the original list so that I get :

> [objB';objC;objD]

I am trying to do the following :

```
let rec resolveConflicts = function
    | [] -> []
    | [c] -> resolveConflict c
    | [x;y] -> resolveConflict x
               |> List.filter getMovesRelatedtoY
               |> List.append y
               |> resolveConflict 
    | [x;y::tail] -> 
               let y' = resolveConflict x
                        |> List.filter getMovesRelatedtoY
                        |> List.append y
               resolveConflicts y'::tail
```

This syntax is not correct, may be I am not even using the correct tool... I am open to any well suited solution so that I can learn.

As to why, I filter the list and append one to another, it is just that every conflict is a list of moves.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To match first element, second element and the rest of the list, use this pattern:

```
| fst::snd::rest ->
```

You can match any constant number of first elements using this styling:

```
| fst::snd::thrd:: ... ::rest ->
```